# How i solve this django project admin operational problem

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin, traceback

When I go to project admin, and do some update on the user and save it, it said this, it always like this I have tried it uninstall django and install it again, create the virtualenv again and new project again, and the result is the same, here's the traceback:
It said

OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/1/change/

no such table: main.auth_user__old

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/auth/user/1/change/

Django Version: 2.0.7
Python Version: 3.9.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  303.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (no such table: main.auth_user__old) was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  128.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  126.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  575.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  223.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in change_view
  1557.         return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  62.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  142.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  58.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1451.             return self._changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in _changeform_view
  1498.                     self.log_change(request, new_object, change_message)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in log_change
  784.         return LogEntry.objects.log_action(

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\models.py" in log_action
  23.         return self.model.objects.create(

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in create
  417.         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save
  728.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in save_base
  759.             updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _save_table
  842.             result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py" in _do_insert
  879.         return manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk,

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _insert
  1125.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1285.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  100.             return super().execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  68.         return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute_with_wrappers
  77.         return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  89.                 raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in _execute
  85.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "C:\Users\user\Dev\trydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  303.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/auth/user/1/change/
Exception Value: no such table: main.auth_user__old
```

I just started learning it on FreeCodeCamp channel and I followed it every step, [youtube](https://youtu.be/F5mRW0jo-U4) but it is always the same when I try it again from 0 any help on it?

Comment: Easiest and risky solution: delete the db, migrations except for __init__.py and re-run makemigrations and migrate them. **You will lose all the data** Try to remove migrations first without deleting the DB, then makemigrations and migrate. If it doesn't work delete the db and re try.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running a table migration?

Here is documentation outlining how to create tables in Django from INSTALLED_APPS.

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#workflow

Answer (score 0):

first of all, make sure that all of your packages are installed.
then, make sure that you have all the migrations files and do a python manage.py migrate.

hope it helps. let me know if i can help!

Answer (score 0):

The following steps should help:
1- Upgrade Django to version 2.1.5 (minimum) using:
`pip install --upgrade django==2.1.5`
2- Prepare and migrate the database:
`python manage.py makemigrations`
`python manage.py migrate`
3- Run the app like usual
`python manage.py runserver 8000`